# FCM Sending HTTP Post request gives error code 400()

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using HTTP POST request to give notification to authors on my web-app that their stories are approved by our admin.

My payload looks like this

```js
var payload = {
  "notification": {
    "title": "Story Approved!",
    "body": "Your story is approved"
  },
  "to" : to
}
```

This is my request

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'key='+serverKey
  },
  data: payload,
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  },
});
```

Whenever I try to send the request it gives me the following error

> POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send 400 ()

I am kinda new to this and according to [Firebase Error Response Codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes)

> Invalid JSON   400    Check that the JSON message is properly formatted and contains valid fields (for instance, making sure the right data type is passed in).

But I cannot figure out where I am wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just convert your payload to json like this:

```
 data: JSON.stringify(msg)
```

and your code will be like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'key='+serverKey
  },
  data: JSON.stringify(msg),
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting Invalid JSON payload. Stating `"payload"` is an unknown name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242019/firebase-cloud-messaging-posting-message-says-invalid-json-payload?noredirect=1#comment95311673_54242019